# For a project with multiple user types across different apps, what is the correct AUTH_USER_MODEL to specify in the settings conf?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a Django 3.2.5 project in which I want to implement the different user types Artist and User (normal site user). I wouldn't want to share one User model and have all user types sharing redundant fields, e.g. a regular site user wouldn't have artist-specific information.

The Django documentation advises that when starting a new project it is best to create a custom user rather than to inherit the built-in User.

I can implement two models, Artist and User (both inheriting AbstractUser) - but what would the value of my AUTH_USER_MODEL config then be?

Comment: Have one user model that has all common fields, for specific fields have extra models with a one to one field with the user model. This is called _specialization_, some research on database design should help you.

Comment: Super helpful. Thank you. I had created a BaseUser model inheriting AbstractUser and then subclassed that for all other user types. I'll refactor for this more idiomatic approach.